# Martingale in $L^2$ equality, williams, probability with martingale p111

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, martingales

[image]

> I am confused how **equality of (e) can be deduced from (f) and (d)**. I was thinking of applying reverse Fatou's lemma, but (f) doesn't really fit in. Any ideas?

Comment: f) follows immediately from d) and Fatou's Lemma. Let $f_r=(M_{n+r} -M_n)^{2}$ and use Fatou's Lemma in the form $\int liminf f_r dP \leq liminf (\int f_r) dP$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: that argument seems to be the same as (e)

Comment: Once one knows by (f) that $M_{n+r}\to M_\infty$ in $L^2$ when $r\to\infty$, for every fixed $n$, one deduces that the LHS of (d) converges to $E((M_\infty-M_n)^2)$ when $r\to\infty$. Since the limit of the RHS is clear, the strengthening of (e) follows. No reverse Fatou lemma here, simply the fact that $X_k\to X$ in $L^2$ implies that, for every $Y$ in $L^2$, $E((X_k-Y)^2)\to E((X-Y)^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to think of it. Let $M'_\infty$ be the $\mathcal L^2$ limit of $M_n.$ Using the $\mathcal L^2$ triangle inequality on the $r\to\infty$ limit of (d) gives (e) with $M'_\infty$ instead of $M_\infty$ and equality instead of inequality. But (f) says $M_\infty=M'_\infty$ as an element of $\mathcal L^2.$